Why is $a(\mathbb{D}(G))=g-\dim V^2(\mathbb{D}(G))$ and not $g-\dim V(\mathbb{D}(G))$?
In A short guide to $p$-torsion of abelian varieties in
characteristic $p$, Pries writes that the $a$-number of a Dieudonné module $\mathbb{D}(G)$ is $g-\dim V^2\mathbb{D}(G)$.
If $G$ is the $p$-torsion of a Jacobian of a curve $J_X[p]$, the action of Verschiebung on $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$ can also be used to compute the $a$-number as the cohomology group is a $k[F,V]$-module (i.e. $k[F,V]$ is the Dieudonné ring $W(k)[F,V]$ modulo $p$). The Verschiebung acting on $H^0(X,\Omega^1)$ has a concrete description as the Cartier operator $\mathcal{C}$. Here the $a$-number can be computed as $g-\operatorname{rank}(\mathcal{C})$ or in other words, $g-\dim_k VH^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$.
Question: Why is $a(\mathbb{D}(G))=g-\dim V^2(\mathbb{D}(G))$ and not $g-\dim V(\mathbb{D}(G))$?
